# Adding line breaks to a Change Set description

Tags: change-set

We do weekly updates via Change Sets and use their Description field to enumerate brief explanations. Example of what I want:

```
1. Fixed problem A
2. Added field "new field"
3. Added workflow X
```

However, I can't seem to get line breaks into the description field, so it all runs together: `1. Fixed problem A 2. Added field "new field" 3. Added workflow X`

I've tried:

- `<br />`
- `BR()`
- `\n`
- Just entering multiple blank lines via the return key

Is there any way to add in line breaks?

Comment: Have you tried just space bar-ing your way to the end of the line and into the next. And then type on the new line. Hopefully it doesn't trim out the whitespaces and actually treats them like characters. Don't think otherwise possible.

Comment: Doesn't work; it trims the extra consecutive spaces when displaying in the read-only view. The spaces and line breaks are there on the edit screen.

Comment: I'm trying to remember what the metadata for formula fields looks like in the Object metadata files. Might be an idea to check what newline character it uses there if they are preserved. Can't remember for the life of me ! If you wanted to be cheeky, you could space bar to the end of the line and put a stop!

Comment: Does escaping the slash work? You may need \\n for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML won't render \n as a new line, and the field probably escapes/encodes HTML.  So the answer is probably no.

Try a comma :)

```
This week we: Fixed problem A, Added field "new field", Added workflow X
```

Or keep the release notes somewhere else and just put in the link:

```
Release notes at:  http://mywiki.net/PROJECT/Release23
```

Answer (score 0):

Without doing something like @techtrekker suggested and inserting spaces and then putting a dot or something I think this is impossible.

Change sets will even eat line breaks in validation rules or [Workflow rule criteria](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hDNwAAM).